# Why are `invisible` and `capture.output` insufficient in removing both concatenated and diagnostic messages in R?

Tags: r, console

I would like to use `invisible` and `capture.output` to remove both concatenated and diagnostic messages. However, it seems that I can only remove one or the other. Here is an example function:

```
func <- function(x){
    message('This is a diagnostic message')
    cat('This is a cat message')
    var <- x^2
    return(var)
}
```

If we use `type = "message"`, we get:

```
> invisible(capture.output(out <- func(5), type = "message"))
This is a cat message
> out
[1] 25
```

but with `type = "output"`, we instead get:

```
> rm(list = "out")
> invisible(capture.output(out <- func(5), type = "output"))
This is a diagnostic message
> out
[1] 25
```

When I do both,

```
> invisible(capture.output(out <- func(5), type = c("output", "message")))
This is a diagnostic message
> out
[1] 25
```

I still get the diagnostic message. Now, if I do

```
> suppressMessages(invisible(capture.output(out <- func(5))))
> out
[1] 25
```

Then it finally seems to work. However, why was having two of the types specified not working? Is it a bug? Are there special cases where having `suppressMessages(invisible(capture.output()))` all together would result in outputs that do not show properly?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`invisible()` sets a flag on a function result so that it won't auto-print.  In your examples, it is setting the invisible flag on the result of `capture.output()`.  In the first example, that's the string

```
[1] "This is a diagnostic message"
```

In the second example, that's

```
[1] "This is a cat message"
```

In the third example you pass both.  Despite the fact that the default value is both, only the first is used.  It's a stupid convention that is very old in the S language.  If you really want to capture both kinds of message, you need to call `capture.output` twice:

```
capture.output(capture.output(out <- func(5), type = "message"), type="output")
```

and if you don't want the result to auto-print, you can wrap it in `invisible()`, or just assign it to a variable:

```
msgs <- capture.output(capture.output(out <- func(5), type = "message"), type="output")
```

Answer (score 1):

There is a function to suppress console messages. Rather unsurprisingly its name is `suppressMessages`.

```
res <- capture.output( suppressMessages(out <- func(5) )  )
# So : 
> res
[1] "This is a cat message"
> out
[1] 25
```